# Azure DevOps pipeline trigger for continuous integration with Github repos

Tags: github, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I'd like to set up two CI/CD pipelines in Azure DevOps for a repo I linked with GitHub.

What I wanted to achieve is to just start the CI pipeline when something arrives to main, so as trigger I did:

```
trigger: 
  branches:
    include:
    - main
```

The problem was that if I made merged a PR, it always triggered two CI pipelines! One called "Individual CI for main" (with the PR merge commit) **and also** another one in parallel called "PR automated for" (with the PR number).

[image: Parallel pipeline run example]

I thought It was implicit to run just once in this case. So I added `pr: none` and It seems to work. **But is it right?** It smells me weird!.

---

The second thing is the CD pipeline. I'd like to trigger the CD pipeline only when a new artifact is uploaded by the CI pipeline (called backend-ci).

I wrote this:

```
trigger: none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: backend
    source: backend-ci
    branch: main
```

I added `trigger: none` because It was always triggering in the same way as the CI pipeline, two parallel CD runs for both the merge commit and the PR closed.

But now It doesn't trigger at all.

---

I also noticed, If I try to edit the pipeline definition by the Azure DevOps GUI, that there are these two "settings" related to GitHub, which I don't understand.

[image: GitHub settings]

Could they be related?

---

What am I doing wrong?